# ngbPopover with html inside

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

Is it possible to put html inside ngbPopover? Exactly, I need to put list of items.
Currently I have this parameters:

```
`ngbPopover="{{column.popup.get(row)}}" triggers="mouseenter:mouseleave" popoverTitle="{{column.popup.title | translate}}" container="body"`
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, but you need to use `<ng-template>` element like so:

```
<ng-template #popContent>Hello, <b>{{name}}</b>!</ng-template>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" [ngbPopover]="popContent" popoverTitle="Fancy content">
  I've got markup and bindings in my popover!
</button>
```

Here is a working plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/re1JbPmiF11Qm3Pf3BtW?p=preview

This is also documented on out demo page: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples